# Exterior Derivative over Quaternions

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, quaternions, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I was wondering if it is possible to define the exterior derivative of a quaternionic valued function. I am doing the quaternionic analogue of a previously complex valued computation, namely something like $\omega = \frac{h}{\sqrt{1+|h|^2}}$ where $h$ is a quaternionic variable and I would like to compute $d\omega$.

Is this possible to do over $H$? In the complex case I treated $z$ and $\bar{z}$ as independent variables and computed using $\omega = \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}$, with $d\omega$ being in terms of $dz$ and $d\bar{z}$.

Comment: Maybe, you can do something similar with more variables. I mean, if $z=a+bi+cj+dk$, then you can define $\overline z=a-bi+cj+dk$, $\overline{\overline z}=a+bi-cj+dk$ and $\overline{\overline{\overline z}}=a+bi+cj-dk$. Then try to write $d\omega$ in terms of $dz$ and so on. I guess it won't work but I think it is worth trying.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! I hadn't thought of doing it like that, my first assumption for the conjugate in this case was $\bar{z} = a -bi -cj-dk$ but that could work. Though how I could relate that to $dh$ and $d\bar{h}$ because I know that given $h = a+bi+cj+dk$ and $\bar{h} = a-bi-cj-dk$, $|h|^2 = \bar{h}h = h\bar{h} = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +d^2$.

Comment: Your $\overline z$ would be the composition of all my $\overline z$. Do you see what I mean? I don't know how to type with symbols. Something like $a-bi-cj-dk =\overline{\overline{\overline{(\overline{\overline{(\overline z)}})}}}$.

Comment: I'm quite sure that my method will fail at some point. But my intention posting that comment was just to shake your mind and to help you finding some different approach. Maybe the answer to your question is 'no, is not possible' but... until that moment...

Comment: @Dog_69 Thank you for giving me a new angle to look at the problem^^ If you think about something too much you can get fixed on a certain method - a shake up is always appreciated!

Comment: What is the domain of your function? If it is $\Bbb H$, you may find [this reference](http://www.theworld.com/~sweetser/quaternions/ps/Quaternionic-analysis.pdf) useful.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you for the reference! Strictly speaking, I am using two coordinates, $h_1$ and $h_2 \in \mathbb{H}^2$ but individually yes in $\mathbb{H}$. I struggled to find any literature on Quaternionic Analysis so this should really help!